# How to delete entire column if cell value is empty in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google sheets and I want to delete the entire column if the cell value is empty. I tried to used the below code snippet to do this. But nothing happens and not prompt any error as well.

```
function DeletColumn() {
  var sheettest = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Data");
  var lr=sheettest.getLastRow()
  var columntest = sheettest.getRange(1, 10, lr).getValues().values;  
    for(var i=0; i<columntest.length ; i++){
      if (columntest[i] ==""){ 
        
      deleteColumn(i);
         
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Issues:

- `sheettest.getRange(1, 10, lr).getValues().values` does not return values but another object `[Function: values]` which has **0** length, therefore your `for` loop terminates before even starts and this is why you are not getting any errors. Remove `.values` and you will get the values.
- `deleteColumn(i)` is a function you **haven't** defined anywhere in your script and therefore it will drop an `undefined` error.
- You don't need to use a `for` loop to check if at least one cell is empty. You can check if a cell is empty. You can simply check if `columntest` [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) at least one empty cell:

  ```
  columntest.includes('')
  ```

### Solution:

```
function DeletColumn() {
  const sheettest = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Data");
  const colNumber = 10;
  const columntest = sheettest.getRange(1, colNumber, sheettest.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  if(columntest.includes('')){
    sheettest.deleteColumn(colNumber);
  }
}
```

### Updated Solution for all columns in the data range:

```
function DeletColumn() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Data");
  const values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  Array(sh.getLastColumn()).fill().map((v,i)=>i).
  reverse().forEach(c=>{                   
        let cTemp = values.map(d => d[c]);
        if(cTemp.includes('')){
           sh.deleteColumn(c+1)
        }                 
  }); 
}
```

**Note that:**

Remember [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) gives the last row with content in the entire sheet and not in the particular column (`J`). For example if the last row with content in column `J` is `15` but in column `A` is `30`, then `sheettest.getLastRow()` will return `30`, assuming that it contains the last row with content of the entire sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but this snippet is not achieved my requirement and it only deletes column 10. But I need to delete each column which includes empty values in particular cells in the mentioned row. Please advice.

Comment: @TharakaWijerama Sorry you said `how to delete entire column` you didn't say `columns` and in your code you specified column `10`. I will update my answer asap.

Comment: @TharakaWijerama please check my updated solution. Please note I use `getDataRange` which gets from last row with content until last column with content. If you want to get the range of the full sheet, then replace `getDataRange()` with `getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn())`

Comment: @TharakaWijerama did the answer work for you?

Comment: Sry for the delayed reply.. It works fine as I expect.

Comment: @TharakaWijerama glad it worked. Consider accepting/upvoting the answer so other readers can identify the solution easier.